# Access collection object in the footer of a repeater

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asprepeater

I have a asp:Repeater that has a DataSourceID to a custom collection.
The collection class has properties that I would like to display in the FooterTemplate. Because it calculate a value based on all the items.

In the FooterTemplate, is there a way to access the actual collection object? Maybe with Container or Eval.

I don't have direct access to the DataSource. I could change the code to have it as a parameter but would rather find an other way.

Answer (score 0):

can you use something like this?

```
rpt.DataSource = mydatasource;
rpt.DataBind();

// label in footer
var lblDateTime = rpt.FindControl("lblDateTime") as Label;
if (lblDateTime != null)
{
   lblDateTime.Text = mydatasource.First().DateChecked;
}
```

or like this

```
void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{ 
    // Execute the following logic for Footer only.
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer) {
        // put code here to get what you want and show it in the footer
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated the question. I don't have direct access to the datasource and .DataSource is nothing since it uses DataSourceID. I could put the collection as a parameter but I want to find an other way.